# Internal Server Error during checkout process

Tags: woocommerce

I have an old Woocommerce 2.2.11 which works fine but after upgrade to 2.3.0 I'm getting Internal Server Error on empty checkout fields processing instead of a red box with error messages.

```
POST http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_checkout 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have checked payment gateway plugin code and validate fields are

```
  public function validate_fields(){
        global $woocommerce;
        if(empty($_POST['cc_num'])){
            $woocommerce->add_error(__('Payment error:', 'woothemes') . " Credit Card Number Must be Filled in.");
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($_POST['exp_month'])||empty($_POST['exp_year'])){
            $woocommerce->add_error(__('Payment error:', 'woothemes') . " Expiration Date Must be Filled in.");
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($_POST['cvv'])){
            $woocommerce->add_error(__('Payment error:', 'woothemes') . " CVV Must be Filled in.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Version 2.6 is in beta right now, so I'd strongly advise getting yourself updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like `$woocommerce->add_error` was deprecated but still exists in the API documentation.